# Registering oracle 10g db with 12c grid

Tags: oracle, database-administration, grid

Hi I have oracle grid infrastructure 12c installed for stand alone server and I'm trying to register oracle database 10g with CRS, but I suspect there was syntax change because srvctl fails when calling srvctl in 10g home outputing usage hint.
full log of command with debugging on:

```
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.477 CET ] [OPSCTLDriver.setInternalDebugLevel:325]  tracing is true at level 2 to file null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.482 CET ] [OPSCTLDriver.main:162]  SRVCTL arguments : args[0]=add args[1]=database args[2]=-d args[3]=IDMTEST args[4]=-o args[5]=/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/ args[6]=-p args[7]=/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/dbs/initIDMTEST.ora 
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.484 CET ] [SRVMContext.init:114]  Performing SRVM Context init. Init Counter=1
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.504 CET ] [Library.load:194]  library.load
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.505 CET ] [sPlatform.isHybrid:66]  osName=Linux osArch=amd64 JVM=64 rc=false
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.505 CET ] [sPlatform.isHybrid:66]  osName=Linux osArch=amd64 JVM=64 rc=false
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.506 CET ] [Library.load:271]  Loading  library /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/lib/libsrvmhas12.so
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.522 CET ] [SRVMContext.init:131]  SRVM Context init-ed
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.538 CET ] [Version.isPre:610]  version to be checked 12.1.0.2.0 major version to check against 10
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.538 CET ] [Version.isPre:621]  isPre.java: Returning FALSE
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.540 CET ] [OCR.loadLibrary:328]  
 Inside constructor of OCR
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.541 CET ] [OCR.loadLibrary:336]  Going to load the ocr library
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.541 CET ] [Library.load:194]  library.load
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.541 CET ] [sPlatform.isHybrid:66]  osName=Linux osArch=amd64 JVM=64 rc=false
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.542 CET ] [sPlatform.isHybrid:66]  osName=Linux osArch=amd64 JVM=64 rc=false
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.542 CET ] [Library.load:271]  Loading  library /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/lib/libsrvmocr12.so
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.542 CET ] [OCR.loadLibrary:338]  loaded ocr libraries
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.543 CET ] [SRVMContext.init:114]  Performing SRVM Context init. Init Counter=2
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.543 CET ] [OCR.isCluster:1000]  Calling OCRNative for isCluster()
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.544 CET ] [OCR.isCluster:1004]  OCR Result status = true
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.544 CET ] [OCR.isCluster:1016]  Bolean result = false
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.545 CET ] [CommandLineParser.<init>:488]  Is this a cluster? : false
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.550 CET ] [CommandLineParser.parse:678]  parsing cmdline args
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.550 CET ] [CommandLineParser.antlrParse:500]  parsing cmdline args using antlr
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.552 CET ] [CommandLineParser.antlrParse:558]  input args are add database -d %OPTVAL%IDMTEST -o %OPTVAL%/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/ -p %OPTVAL%/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/dbs/initIDMTEST.ora 
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.580 CET ] [SrvExprParser.optverb:826]  antlr: Match verb
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.581 CET ] [SrvExprParser.optnoun:873]  antlr: Match noun
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.582 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for help
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.582 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.582 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for HELP
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.582 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.583 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for file
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.583 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.583 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for output
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.583 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.584 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for compatible
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.584 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.584 CET ] [SrvExprParser.optval:906]  antlr: Call initOptVals for add database
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.584 CET ] [CmdOptVals.setOptionChoices:1249]  Set option choices in the hashmap for -role
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.585 CET ] [CmdOptVals.setOptionChoices:1249]  Set option choices in the hashmap for -policy
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.585 CET ] [SrvExprParser.optval:946]  antlr: Getting OPTION VALUE
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.586 CET ] [SrvExprParser.optval:948]  antlr: Set -d value: %OPTVAL%IDMTEST
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.586 CET ] [CmdOptVals.checkAndSet:734]  Calling checkAndSet for -d = -d
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.587 CET ] [CmdOptVals.checkAndSet:802]  Calling checkAndSet for OptEnum db = IDMTEST
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.587 CET ] [OptVal.check:180]  Value IDMTEST for option db will be set.
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.587 CET ] [OptVal.check:221]  db = IDMTEST
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.587 CET ] [SrvExprParser.optval:946]  antlr: Getting OPTION VALUE
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.588 CET ] [SrvExprParser.optval:948]  antlr: Set -o value: %OPTVAL%/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.588 CET ] [CmdOptVals.checkAndSet:734]  Calling checkAndSet for -o = -o
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.588 CET ] [CmdOptVals.checkAndSet:802]  Calling checkAndSet for OptEnum oraclehome = /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.589 CET ] [OptVal.check:180]  Value /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/ for option oraclehome will be set.
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.589 CET ] [OptVal.check:221]  oraclehome = /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.589 CET ] [SrvExprParser.optval:946]  antlr: Getting OPTION VALUE
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.589 CET ] [SrvExprParser.optval:948]  antlr: Set -p value: %OPTVAL%/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/dbs/initIDMTEST.ora
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.590 CET ] [CmdOptVals.checkAndSet:734]  Calling checkAndSet for -p = -p
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.590 CET ] [CmdOptVals.checkAndSet:802]  Calling checkAndSet for OptEnum spfile = /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/dbs/initIDMTEST.ora
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.590 CET ] [OptVal.check:180]  Value /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/dbs/initIDMTEST.ora for option spfile will be set.
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.591 CET ] [OptVal.check:221]  spfile = /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/dbs/initIDMTEST.ora
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.591 CET ] [SrvExprParser.cmdline:529]  antlr: Set verb and noun and options
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.591 CET ] [SrvExprParser.srvrule:219]  antlr: Return optvals
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.591 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for file
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.592 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.592 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for help
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.592 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.592 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for db
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.593 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is IDMTEST
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.593 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for oraclehome
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.593 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.593 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for db
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.594 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is IDMTEST
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.594 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for database
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.594 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.594 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for db
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.595 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is IDMTEST
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.595 CET ] [CmdOptVals.checkRefChoices:1066]  in checkRefChoices
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.595 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for output
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.595 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.596 CET ] [OPSCTLDriver.main:215]  Attempting to register interrupt handler for OPSCTL driver
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.598 CET ] [InterruptHandler.registerInterruptHandler:60]  Registering shutdown hook.....
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.599 CET ] [InterruptHandler.registerInterruptHandler:62]  Registered shutdown hook.....
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.599 CET ] [SRVCTLHandler.registerInterruptHandler:86]  Registered interrupt handler for OPSCTL driver
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.600 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for compatible
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.600 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.600 CET ] [OPSCTLDriver.execute:345]  checking for -H option: print verbose command syntax
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.600 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for HELP
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.601 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for help
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.601 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.601 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for HELP_H
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.601 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for HELP
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.602 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.612 CET ] [CRSCache.<clinit>:74]  CRSCache: useCache is false
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.613 CET ] [OPSCTLDriver.execute:411]  executing 2-word command verb=7 noun=101
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.645 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for eval
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.645 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.646 CET ] [AddAction.executeSIHADatabase:512]  Getting optional arguments
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.647 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for DOMAIN_DB
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.647 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for domain
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.647 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.648 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for SPFILE
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.648 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for spfile
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.648 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/dbs/initIDMTEST.ora
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.648 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for DB_ROLE
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.649 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for role
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.649 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.649 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for STARTOPTION
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.649 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for startoption
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.650 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.650 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for STOPOPTION
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.650 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for stopoption
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.650 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.651 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for DBNAME
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.651 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for dbname
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.651 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.651 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for DISKGROUP_A
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.652 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for diskgroup
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.652 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.652 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for DB_POLICY
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.652 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for policy
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.653 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.653 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:917]  Check isOptionSet for INSTANCE
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.653 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for instance
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.653 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.654 CET ] [CmdOptVals.isOptionSet:861]  Calling isOptionSet for pwfile
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.654 CET ] [OptVal.isSet:150]  m_value is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.654 CET ] [AddAction.executeSIHADatabase:515]  Creating database now
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.671 CET ] [DatabaseFactoryImpl.getInstance:320]  s_instance is null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.671 CET ] [DatabaseFactoryImpl.getInstance:323]  before returning object
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.686 CET ] [HASContext.<init>:125]  moduleInit = 7
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.686 CET ] [SRVMContext.init:114]  Performing SRVM Context init. Init Counter=3
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.686 CET ] [HASContext.<init>:136]  Initialised SRVMContext
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.687 CET ] [Util.<init>:103]  Util Instance created.
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.688 CET ] [HASContext.getCRSHome:642]  /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.689 CET ] [Util.getCRSHome:612]  getCRSHome: ret=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.689 CET ] [Util.<init>:103]  Util Instance created.
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.689 CET ] [HASContext.getCRSHome:642]  /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.690 CET ] [Util.getCRSHome:612]  getCRSHome: ret=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.690 CET ] [Version.isPre:610]  version to be checked 12.1.0.2.0 major version to check against 12
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.690 CET ] [Version.isPre:621]  isPre.java: Returning FALSE
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.692 CET ] [SRVCTLUtil.<init>:96]  Check /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db//bin/srvctl
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.694 CET ] [SRVCTLUtil.runCommand:173]  Env value of SRVM_TRACE is : TRUE
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.694 CET ] [SRVCTLUtil.runCommand:176]  After remove, Env value of SRVM_TRACE is : null
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.694 CET ] [SRVCTLUtil.runCommand:188]  OS Name is...Linux
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.696 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:135]  Calling Runtime.exec() with the command 
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.696 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:137]  /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db//bin/srvctl 
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.696 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:137]  -V 
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.696 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:137]  -inner 
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.697 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:137]  1 
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.697 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:140]  runCommand: m_env = 
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.697 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   0:TERM=xterm-256color
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.697 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   1:ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.698 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   2:SHLVL=2
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.698 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   3:XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.698 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   4:ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.698 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   5:SSH_CLIENT=10.0.1.105 34386 22
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.699 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   6:LC_NUMERIC=cs_CZ.utf8
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.699 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   7:MAIL=/var/spool/mail/oracle
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.699 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   8:PWD=/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/bin
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.700 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   9:SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.700 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   10:HOSTNAME=oradb2.test.ntkcz.cz
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.700 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   11:SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.700 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   12:LOGNAME=oracle
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.701 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   13:LC_PAPER=cs_CZ.utf8
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.701 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   14:_=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/jdk/bin/java
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.701 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   15:XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.701 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   16:NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.702 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   17:SSH_CONNECTION=10.0.1.105 34386 10.0.12.220 22
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.702 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   18:LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/jdk/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/jdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/lib:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/srvm/lib:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/lib
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.702 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   19:SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.702 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   20:SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.703 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   21:SHELL=/bin/bash
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.703 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   22:HISTSIZE=1000
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.703 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   23:_CRS_UI_FMT=-v
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.703 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   24:PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/bin
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.704 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   25:DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.704 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   26:LC_MONETARY=cs_CZ.utf8
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.704 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   27:USER=oracle
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.704 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   28:HOME=/home/oracle
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.705 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   29:HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.705 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   30:LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.705 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   31:ORACLE_SID=IDMTEST
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.705 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   32:XDG_SESSION_ID=628
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.705 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   33:LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.706 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   34:LC_TIME=cs_CZ.utf8
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.706 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   35:LC_MEASUREMENT=cs_CZ.utf8
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.706 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   36:XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/54323
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.707 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   37:LANG=en_US.utf8
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.707 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   38:ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.707 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   39:LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.707 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:142]   40:LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
[Thread-2] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.712 CET ] [StreamReader.run:61]  In StreamReader.run 
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.712 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:207]  runCommand: Waiting for the process
[Thread-1] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.713 CET ] [StreamReader.run:61]  In StreamReader.run 
[Thread-1] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.872 CET ] [StreamReader.run:65]  OUTPUT>Usage: srvctl <command> <object> [<options>]
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.920 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:209]  runCommand: process returns 1
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.921 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:226]  RunTimeExec: output>
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.921 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:229]  Usage: srvctl <command> <object> [<options>]
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.922 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:235]  RunTimeExec: error>
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.922 CET ] [RuntimeExec.runCommand:257]  Returning from RunTimeExec.runCommand
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.923 CET ] [CmdToolUtil.doexecuteLocally:902]  retval =  1
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.923 CET ] [CmdToolUtil.doexecuteLocally:903]  exitval =  1
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.923 CET ] [CmdToolUtil.doexecuteLocally:904]  rtErrLength =  0
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.924 CET ] [CmdToolUtil.doexecuteLocally:929]  Failed to execute command.
 Command = [/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db//bin/srvctl, -V, -inner, 1]
 env = [TERM=xterm-256color, ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid, SHLVL=2, XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt, ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle, SSH_CLIENT=10.0.1.105 34386 22, LC_NUMERIC=cs_CZ.utf8, MAIL=/var/spool/mail/oracle, PWD=/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/bin, SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=, HOSTNAME=oradb2.test.ntkcz.cz, SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0, LOGNAME=oracle, LC_PAPER=cs_CZ.utf8, _=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/jdk/bin/java, XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus, NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat, SSH_CONNECTION=10.0.1.105 34386 10.0.12.220 22, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/jdk/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/jdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/lib:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/srvm/lib:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/lib, SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=, SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=, SHELL=/bin/bash, HISTSIZE=1000, _CRS_UI_FMT=-v, PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/grid/bin, DISPLAY=localhost:10.0, LC_MONETARY=cs_CZ.utf8, USER=oracle, HOME=/home/oracle, HISTCONTROL=ignoredups, LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s, ORACLE_SID=IDMTEST, XDG_SESSION_ID=628, LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:, LC_TIME=cs_CZ.utf8, LC_MEASUREMENT=cs_CZ.utf8, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/54323, LANG=en_US.utf8, ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db/, LANG=en_US.UTF-8, LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8]
 error = Usage: srvctl <command> <object> [<options>]

[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.932 CET ] [DatabaseFactoryImpl.versionCheck:4040]  Exception caught while retrieving version of srvm
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.946 CET ] [InterruptHandler.unRegisterInterruptHandler:76]  UNRegistering shutdown hook.....
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.947 CET ] [InterruptHandler.unRegisterInterruptHandler:81]  UnRegistered shutdown hook.....
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.947 CET ] [OPSCTLDriver.main:242]  OPSCTL execute() failed. Unregistered OPSCTL driver's interrupt handler
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.948 CET ] [OPSCTLDriver.main:247]  exiting abnormally due to FrameworkException
PRCD-1025 : Failed to create database IDMTEST
PRCT-1011 : Failed to run "srvctl". Detailed error: Usage: srvctl <command> <object> [<options>]

[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.967 CET ] [OPSCTLDriver.main:249]  PRCD-1025 : Failed to create database IDMTEST
PRCT-1011 : Failed to run "srvctl". Detailed error: Usage: srvctl <command> <object> [<options>]

oracle.ops.opsctl.AddAction.executeSIHADatabase(AddAction.java:526)
oracle.ops.opsctl.Action.executeSIHA(Action.java:357)
oracle.ops.opsctl.OPSCTLDriver.execute(OPSCTLDriver.java:504)
oracle.ops.opsctl.OPSCTLDriver.main(OPSCTLDriver.java:231)
[main] [ 2017-03-17 12:35:43.967 CET ] [SRVMContext.term:151]  Performing SRVM Context Term. Term counter is 2
```

Does anybody met this error? Is there a way to add 10g db to 12c grid?